# Fork() is not returning an id > 0 in the parent process

Tags: c, unix, fork

I am currently trying to learn about fork() and processes in general.

I have the task to perform fork() a certain amount of times - n - which the user can enter. Also, I am supposed to use waitpid() to wait for the termination of my process. Each process is supposed to return a random number beetween 1 and 6.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int n,i;
  int *returnvalue;
  int pid;
  int waitingID;

  time_t t;
  srand((unsigned)time(&t));

  printf("How many processes to start?\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);

  for(i=0; i < n; i++){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid==0){
      printf("I am %d, from iteration %d\n",getpid(), i);
    }
    else if(pid > 0){
      waitingID = waitpid(pid, returnvalue, 0);
      printf("Return-value of %d is: %d\n", waitingID, *returnvalue);
    }
    else{
      printf("A problem occured.");
    }
  }

  return rand()%6;
}
```

Here is an example output of the current program:

```
How many processes to start?
5
I am 6449, from iteration 0
I am 6450, from iteration 1
I am 6451, from iteration 2
I am 6452, from iteration 3
I am 6453, from iteration 4
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As you can see, I have a few problems:

The `else if (pid>0)` is not being called at all. Therefore no waiting happens. Shouldn't this be called in each fork, for the corresponding parent process?

Also, as soon as the last iteration is over and it gets to the return, I get that Segmentation fault(core dumped) error.

I am lost right now. I can't quite figure out where my mistake is at.

Comment: `fork()` does not return an `int` - it returns `pid_t`.  See http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork  While a specific implementation may define `pid_t` as an `int`, that doesn't mean `pid_t` **is** an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int *returnvalue;
```

This is just a *pointer* to `int`, but pointing nowhere defined, so this:

```
waitingID = waitpid(pid, returnvalue, 0);
```

will write the status code to some random memory location that probably doesn't belong to your process (in terms of [c](/questions/tagged/c), it is undefined behaviour to write through an uninitialized pointer).

Simple thing to do, instead of defining a pointer, define an actual `int` variable:

```
int returnvalue;
```

and pass a pointer to that variable:

```
waitingID = waitpid(pid, &returnvalue, 0);
```

Comment: I see it now! How could I not notice that... It's been a long time without basic C...

Answer (score 1):

You don't get any output for the parent case because the parent process `waitpid` is causing the segmentation fault. `returnvalue` is any uninitialised pointer. You need to do this:

```
int returnvalue;
...
pid = fork();
if(pid==0){
  printf("I am %d, from iteration %d\n",getpid(), i);
}
else if(pid > 0){
  waitingID = waitpid(pid, &returnvalue, 0);
  printf("Return-value of %d is: %d\n", waitingID, returnvalue);
}
```

But even that isn't really what you want. The return value from `waitpid` should not be used as is. You need to use the `WIF` macros to determine the child exist status and then use `WEXITSTATUS` macro to get the return value. This is the example from the man page:

```
if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("exited, status=%d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
} else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
     printf("killed by signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
} else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
     printf("stopped by signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
} else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)) {
     printf("continued\n");
}
```

Comment: Well I'd say: 1.) no, the first problem occurs already in `waitpid()` trying to write to whatever random location `returnvalue` points to, but 2.) good added advice on how to treat the status code.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Ah, you're right. The `printf` is a problem but the `waitpid` precedes it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `waitpid` tries to write to the storage pointed to by `returnvalue`. In your code `returnvalue` hasn't been initialized and thus 
it's value is undefined.

Since `waitpid` is trying to write to an unknown address, it is causing a crash.

One way to mitigate this as suggested by others is to use `int returnvalue` and then pass its address as `&returnvalue` to `waitpid`.
This way since the variable `returnvalue` is created on stack, its address is welldefined and `waitpid` can write to it as well.

One other value that you can do is, although it is not very efficient is to call `malloc` and give your pointer a address(storage which will be created on the heap as opposed to the stack) so that you can then pass it to `waitpid`. But don't forget to call `free` on it afterwards.

```
returnvalue = malloc(sizeof(int));
waitingID = waitpid(pid, returnvalue, 0);
printf("Return-value of %d is: %d\n", waitingID, *returnvalue);
free(returnvalue);
```